# Selecting from database where one field has the most number value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I am sure there is a way to do this, but being that I am still new to MySQL and PHP, I can't figure this out.

I have a table where the first column (base_folder) represents a folder, there are multiple images in that folder (sub_folder). The last field (layer) represents the image order. What I need to get is the max number from the layer column where the base_folder, the sub_folder, image_, image_type and view are identical.

Does anyone have any idea how to do to that?

Here is the table:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                BASE_IMAGE                               |
+-----+-------------+------------+-------------+----------+-------+-------+
| id  | base_folder | sub_folder | image       |image_type|  view | layer |          
+-----+-------------+------------+-------------+----------+-------+-------+
|  1  | CUP0001     |   F        | B_FF_0.png  |   B      |   FF  |   0   |
+-----+-------------+------------+-------------+----------+-------+-------+
|  2  | CUP0001     |   F        | B_FF_0.png  |   B      |   FF  |   1   |
+-----+-------------+------------+-------------+----------+-------+-------+
|  3  | CUP0001     |   F        | B_FF_0.png  |   B      |   FF  |   2   |
+-----+-------------+------------+-------------+----------+-------+-------+
|  4  | CUP0001     |   F        | B_FF_0.png  |   M      |   FF  |   0   |
+-----+-------------+------------+-------------+----------+-------+-------+
```

What I would like to get is "2" for where the base_folder['CUP0001'], sub_folder['F'], image['B_FF_0.png'], image_type['B'], view['FF'], layer['2']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct answer to the original question is:

```
SELECT MAX(layer)
  FROM Base_Image
 WHERE Base_Folder = 'CUP0001'
   AND Sub_Folder  = 'F'
   AND Image       = 'B_FF_0.png'
   AND Image_Type  = 'B'
   AND View        = 'FF';
```

If you need the maximum layer for each combination of the five fields, then you need a GROUP BY clause and you need to select the identifying columns too:

```
SELECT Base_Folder, Sub_Folder, Image, Image_Type, View, MAX(layer) AS MaxLayer
  FROM Base_Image
 GROUP BY Base_Folder, Sub_Folder, Image, Image_Type, View;
```

(*Withdrawn:* 
<s>It looks suspiciously as if your table is not properly normalized; there is at least room to suppose that the combination of Base_Folder, Sub_Folder, Image controls the values of Image_Type and View.  However, the code shown will work whether this comment is accurate or not.</s>)

---

> If the long combinations are not good, [...] do you have a suggestion on a better approach?

It depends on the volume of data, and how you're going to be managing the data.  It also depends on which parts of the data are independent.  I would be tempted to split the table into two, though an extreme view might go as far as five tables:

- **ImageFile** columns (ID, Base_Folder, Sub_Folder, Image) with primary key ID and alternate key (unique constraint) on (Base_Folder, Sub_Folder, Image).
- **ImageDetails** (ID, ImageFileID, Image_Type, View, Layer, with primary key ID, alternate key (ImageFileID, Image_Type, View, Layer), and foreign key ImageFileID referencing ImageFile.ID.

An alternative design for ImageDetails avoids the ID column and uses the alternate key as the primary key.  It depends, in part, on whether anything else is going to reference the rows in this table.

However, it all depends on what you're going to do and how the data is really organized (what the functional dependencies are in the table you show).  The extreme view would use: one table for the base folders; then there'd be a sub-folder table with a base folder ID and the sub-folder name an its own ID field, and then there'd be an image file table with its own ID, a sub-folder ID, and the image name; then there'd be an image type table for each image type of each image file (with its own ID plus an FK); and so on.  This is harder to insert rows into; and every select operation that needs to filter on, say, base folder and image type needs to join a lot of tables.  That needn't be slow, but it complicates the SQL.

Comment: It doesn't seem that this combination controls Image_Type as there are two types, `B` and `M` for same combination. But having same and long combinations (like `base_folder,sub_folder,image`) repeating many times is not good for sure.

Comment: Ok thank you. If the long combinations are not good, which I can see why it would be, do you have a suggestion on a better approach?

Comment: @ypercube - I didn't look carefully enough at ID = 4.  You're right that the 'M' for image type means that image type is part of the identification; maybe the view is too.  That wasn't a major part of my argument, fortunately.

Comment: Yes, but it's still true that having so many repeating fields may not be a normalization problem in theory while in practise it means that an index on `(Base_Folder, Sub_Folder, Image, Image_Type, View)`, which is useful for this query, would be enormous. As the `image` field is probably some big Varchar. So, your suspicion is probably good.

Comment: Would there be a better method to accomplish the same results?

Answer (score 2):

Use `GROUP BY` and the `MAX` aggregate:

```
SELECT MAX(layer) AS max_layer, base_folder, sub_folder, image, image_type, view
       FROM base_image
       GROUP BY base_folder, sub_folder, image, image_type, view;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your SQL statement...

```
SELECT ........ ORDER BY 'layer' DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: +1: Works too, but `MAX` is supported on all databases - `LIMIT` is only on MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
      base_folder, sub_folder, image, image_type, view
    , MAX(layer)
FROM 
    BASE_IMAGE
GROUP BY
      base_folder, sub_folder, image, image_type, view
ORDER BY
      base_folder, sub_folder, image, image_type, view
```

Comment: This should be the right solution, but you should order just by `layer` `DESC` or omit it altogether.

Comment: @Shf: The Order can be omitted or altered, it doesn't really matter for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    MAX(layer)
FROM 
    table 
WHERE 
       image_type = 'B' AND 
       image = 'B_FF_0.png' AND 
       view = 'FF' AND 
       layer = '2' AND 
       sub_folder = 'F'
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess I should have specified that there are other potential folders than just one. This would work if there was just one entry. Sorry for my lack of clarification here.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach would probably be to use the `MAX()` function, together with a subquery. However, this is not very efficient.

Another, better solution is to abuse the `ORDER BY` clause, like this:

```
SELECT <your fields>
FROM `BASE_IMAGE`
WHERE <your conditions>
ORDER BY `layer` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The `ORDER BY` clause causes the largest `id` to be on top, and the `LIMIT` clause cuts off all the rest, so you only get the topmost result.

Comment: `MAX()` is as efficient as `ORDER BY - LIMIT`. This is only better if you want to show other fields besides the MAXed one.